# How to get coordinates in Petrel 2d Mapwindow through mouse click event?

Tags: ocean, petrel

How to get coordinates dynamically in Petrel 2d Mapwindow through mouse click event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you implement a custom WindowMode, you can access the coordinates via the PickedPoint API. The "World" property will give you the X-Y coordinates in world space, and the Z is determined by the domain object (if any) under the mouse cursor.

There is also a separate window-based coordinate system that uses fixed spacing X and Y coordinates based on the Map viewport.

Comment: Hi @Deepak, welcome to StackOverflow. If Origameg's answer worked for you please upvote and mark answer as accepted.

Comment: MapPickedPoint mpPickedPoint = args as MapPickedPoint;
                    if (mpPickedPoint == null)
                        return;
                    xcoor = mpPickedPoint.World.X;
                    ycoor = mpPickedPoint.World.Y; this is working for Metric system but it is giving different coordinates for Field system, what changes do I have to make for Field system to get exact coordinates?